# Modifying my SharePoint upper ribbon boarder color is not working well

Tags: html, css, master-pages

I have a Ribbon in side my SharePoint , which have different board color, depending on the tab i am displaying, so i want to have the ribbon boarder to always be blue. So using Firebug i have detected the classes which is responsible for the ribbon as follow:-
[image]

[image]

I added the following code to my cusotm CSS:-

```
.ms-cui-tabBody{
    border-color:#008CD2 #008CD2 #008CD2 #008CD2 !important;
    border-top-color:#008CD2 !important;

}
.ms-cui-tabBody.ms-cui-tabBody-gr{
    border-color:#008CD2 #008CD2 #008CD2 #008CD2 !important;
border-top-color:#008CD2 !important;
}
```

But unfortunately this has changed only the buttom boarder colour to be blue, while the “Calendar” tab still have green upper boarder, and “Page Option” tab have no upper boarder color ? can anyone advice on how I can change the boarder to be all blue? Thanks.

Comment: can you create [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) of what you have done?

Comment: unfortunatly this will not be easy as i am working on SharePoint web page, and most markup is generated by SharePoint , and i did not wrote them.